# Can I connect to multiple databases in CherryPy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

`cherrypy.engine` `subscribe()`s a function to connect to a database, and this `cherrypy.engine` `start()`s with that database subscribed.

If I want to fetch multiple sets of data from different databases, I would need to connect to different databases.

Is there any way to do it in CherryPy without too much change in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use 2 cursors or at least initialize the same one twice.  Try something like this...

```
import cherrypy 
import MySQLdb 

def connect(thread_index): 
    # Create a connection and store it in the current thread 
    cherrypy.thread_data.db = MySQLdb.connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'dbname') 
    cherrypy.thread_data.db2 = MySQLdb.connect('host', 'user', 'password', 'dbname2') 

# Tell CherryPy to call "connect" for each thread, when it starts up 
cherrypy.engine.subscribe('start_thread', connect)


class Root: 
    def index(self): 
        # Sample page that displays the number of records in "table" 
        # Open a cursor, using the DB connection for the current thread 
        c = cherrypy.thread_data.db.cursor() 
        c.execute('select count(*) from table') 
        res = c.fetchone() 
        c.close() 

        c = cherrypy.thread_data.db2.cursor() 
        c.execute('select count(*) from table2') 
        res = c.fetchone() 
        return "<html><body>Hello, you have %d records in your table</body></html>" % res[0] 
    index.exposed = True 

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to put the cherrypy.thread_data.db(and db2) objects in a dictionary using the name of the db as the key?

Comment: Is this what you mean?  dict1 = {'dbname': cherrypy.thread_data.db, 'dbname2': cherrypy.thread_data.db2}